# Gunicorn + Django + supervisor: Where are my logs?

Tags: python, django, logging, gunicorn, supervisord

I'm using supervisor to manage gunicorn (behind Apache) + Django.

My Django LOGGING config:

```
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "formatters": {
        "verbose": {
            "format": "%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s "
                      "%(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s"
        }
    },
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "verbose",
        }
    },
    "root": {"level": "INFO", "handlers": ["console"]},
    "loggers": {
        "django.db.backends": {
            "level": "ERROR",
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "propagate": False,
        },

        # Errors logged by the SDK itself
        "sentry_sdk": {"level": "ERROR", "handlers": ["console"], "propagate": False},

        "django.security.DisallowedHost": {
            "level": "ERROR",
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "propagate": False,
        },
        'gunicorn.error': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'gunicorn.access': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
}
```

my gunicorn config:
`--preload --pid /usr/home/pids/%(program_name)s -b 127.0.0.1:8124 --access-logfile /usr/home/logs/user/access_%(program_name)s.log --access-logformat "%%({x-forwarded-for}i)s %%(l)s %%(u)s %%(t)s \"%%(r)s\" %%(s)s %%(b)s \"%%(f)s\" \"%%(a)s\""`

my supervisor config:

```
stdout_logfile=/usr/home/logs/user/%(program_name)s.stdout.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=10MB
stderr_logfile=/usr/home/logs/user/%(program_name)s.stderr.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=10MB
```

Somehow my access log ends up in /usr/home/logs/user/%(program_name)s.stderr.log, all other logs are and stay empty (except for Apache, which also creates an access log). Since I changed "disable_existing_loggers" from True to False, now also errors end up in that log file (before they only went to sentry).

Any thoughts what is going on?

When I used the same LOGGING and nginx -> apache -> mod_wsgi -> django, I did receive the error in my nginx log.

Comment: If I'd made a log entry for every time I got bitten by the Django loggers, I'd at least have some freaking log entries!